# Google-maps addLayer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary

I am currently using google maps. As it is an older version, the library does not include addLayer(). Here is the codes:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

So whenever I tried to add a layer by using this function:

```
map.addLayer(heatLayer);
```

It prompts me an error message about undefined is not a function. I wonder is there any alternate way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to add heatmap layer you have to use `HeatmapLayer` constructor. See [heatmaps example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps)

Comment: @AntoJurković But doesn't it has a addLayer function in library? Cause I saw it from nowhere in this tutorial: http://tmappsevents.esri.com/stage/heatmap/

Comment: But that is written using ArcGIS library which doesn't use google api.

Comment: @AntoJurković So what is your suggestion? Refractors all the codes?